# C#でURLからJSONファイルを取得しパースする

Tags: c#, json, http

http://cathval.com/csharp/4159
こちらのサイトを参考にJSONデータを扱う方法がわかったのですが、下記のURLのようなWebAPIからのJSONの情報ををStringで受け取るにはどのようにしたらよいのでしょうか？

http://weather.livedoor.com/forecast/webservice/json/v1?city=400040

Comment: JSONデータをパースした結果のデータが欲しいのか、JSONデータを文字列で取得できればよいのか、タイトルと本文が食い違っているのですがどちらを求めているのでしょうか

Answer (score 4):

`HttpWebRequest`系のクラスを使うこともできますが、
[WebClient クラス](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) の[WebClient.DownloadString メソッド](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring(v=vs.110).aspx) を使うのが簡単です。

以下使用例。

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace HTTPGET
{
    class HttpGet
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using(WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                string str = webClient.DownloadString("http://weather.livedoor.com/forecast/webservice/json/v1?city=400040");
                Console.Write(str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @mttn ああ、なるほど。 編集ありがとうございます。まあ、好きずきのような気もしますが、一般的にはベターなんだと思いますｗ。

Comment: usingを使うとtry/finally相当になるので、（元のコードと比べて）例外発生時にもきちんとDisposeが行われるという違いはあります。

Answer (score 4):

RESTful serviceを作りたかったら、[ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api)はこんな目指を考慮して設計されていました。

例えば、[HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx)というクラスを使うと簡単にasyncで受け取れます。

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;　// nugetで`System.Net.Http`か`Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`をインストすると使える。


namespace httpclient_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string uri = "http://weather.livedoor.com/forecast/webservice/json/v1?city=400040";
            GetString(uri).Wait();
        }

        public static async Task GetString(string uri)
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                string response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
                Console.Write(response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

.NETでHTTPリクエストを送信する場合の基本は`WebRequest`です。`WebClient`や`HttpClient`も内部的には`WebRequest`を使用しています。

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var req = WebRequest.Create("http://weather.livedoor.com/forecast/webservice/json/v1?city=400040");

        using (var res = req.GetResponse())
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

また解析結果だけが欲しいのであれば`String`ではなくて`Stream`をパラメーターにすべきかと思います。

```
dynamic json; 
using (var res = req.GetResponse())
using (var s = res.GetResponseStream())
{
    json = DynamicJson.Parse(s);
}
```